# Sending to dynamic address endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How can one send an email to a dynamic address?
Address endpoint's URI seem to be static.
Is there a way to inject a property in a address endpoint ?

Here is what I have so far :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="sendMail" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property expression="//email" name="email" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="fn:concat('Sending mail to - ',get-property('mail'))" name="mail"/>
    </log>
    <property name="messageType" value="text/html" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="ContentType" value="text/html" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="Subject" value="File Received" scope="transport"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint name="mail2user">
            <address uri="mailto:username@gmail.com"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define header "To" and use send without endpoint :

```
<header name="To"expression="fn:concat('mailto:', get-property('senderAddress'))"/>
<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
<send/>
```

Don't forget to define transportSender "mailto" with class "org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender" in axis2.xml

Comment: It is not clear how I should use these `<header>` and `<property>` mediators... I appended my current sequence to the initial post... thanks...

Comment: ok. I got it. your code is just fine. I just had to remove endpoint. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code after [jean-michel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2919375/jean-michel) suggestion :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="sendMail" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property expression="//email" name="mailto" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="fn:concat('Sending mail to - ',get-property('mailto'))" name="mail"/>
    </log>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>
    <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>
    <property name="Subject" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="File Received"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <header expression="fn:concat('mailto:', get-property('mailto'))" name="To" scope="default"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <send/>
</sequence>
```